# How to calculate this by vector?

Tags: r

[image]Updated: Now it's working, but still don't konw how the other way work.

```
 cuts <- seq(from=3, to=36, by=0.01)

    for (i in cuts) {
      cut_off<- i
      set.seed(666)
      samp_h <-rnorm(1000,mean=12,sd=3)
      samp_d <-rnorm(1000,mean=18,sd=6)
      a <- sum(samp_h <= cut_off)
      c <- sum(samp_h > cut_off)
      b <- sum(samp_d <= cut_off)
      d <- sum(samp_d > cut_off)
      sens <- a / (a+c)
      spci <- d / (d+b)
      assign(paste("ss",as.character(cut_off),sep = ""), sens)
      assign(paste("sp",as.character(cut_off),sep = ""), spci)}

    ss_v<- unlist(
      lapply(               
        paste0("ss",cuts), 
        get)              
    )

    sp_v<- unlist(
      lapply(               
        paste0("sp",cuts), 
        get)              
    )

    plot(1-sp_v, ss_v)
```

Hi all:
   I was trying to use different 'cut_off' to get different 'sens' (sensitive) and 'spci' (spcificity). The problem for code above is that for 34 'cuts', i can get the result. but if i change the cuts to:

```
cuts <- seq(from=3, to=36, by=0.01)
```

This method can't return the results. The problem is that I calculate the number in each vector, so I am asking how to use the vector to calculate the "ss_v" and "ss_p" directly. Thank you very much.

Background information:
Suppose that in ‘healthy’ patients antibody levels are distributed Normal(12,32) and in ‘diseased’ patients antibodies are distributed Normal(18,62). Note that these are ‘made up’ numbers and not intended to be realistic.
Simulate antibody counts for a large number of diseased and healthy patients (e.g. 1000 of each) – using the ‘rnorm’ function in R. What would the sensitivity and specificity be if a cutoff of 15 was chosen?
Record the sensitivity and specificity for a range of cutoffs between 3 and 36 (e.g. 3, 3.01, 3.02, …, 35.98, 35.99, 36). Hint: generate the cutoffs using the ‘seq’ function in R and then calculate the sensitivity and specificity using a ‘for’ loop or a vectorised calculation.
Produce a plot with ‘1-Specificity’ in the x-axis and ‘Sensitivity’ in the y-axis.

Comment: So instead of analyzing them separately you could create a two column object with 2000 rows with "group* containing the "truth" and "values" that represent the antibody counts. I think using a skewed distribution is likely to be more "biological". whether you accept my suggestion to use log-normal or gamma random variables you will then be in a postiion to use the `table` function properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is an example of trying to use R as a macro language. Better would be learning how to use R vectors properly. Since you used a `for`-loop, you should pre-allocate `sens` and `spci` and  instead assign to  `sens` and `spci` as indexed vectors. (So I am endorsing your request for a vector of results as teh sensible way to go.) Then give the vectors names, rather than littering your workspace with a profusion of individual, disconnected named objects. Try this instead:

```
cuts <- seq(from=3, to=36, by=1)
sens <- numeric(length(cuts)); spci=numeric(length(cuts))
for (i in cuts) {
  cut_off<- i
  set.seed(666)
  samp_h <-rnorm(1000,mean=12,sd=3)
  samp_d <-rnorm(1000,mean=18,sd=6)
  hth <- table(samp_h)
  dis <-table(samp_d)
  a<-length(hth[names(hth) <= cut_off])
  c<-length(hth[names(hth) > cut_off])
  b <-length(dis[names(dis) <= cut_off])
  d <-length(dis[names(dis) > cut_off])
  sens[i] <- a / (a+c)
  spci[1] <- d / (d+b)
} 
 names(sens) <- paste0("ss",cuts)  
 names(spci) <- paste0("sp",cuts)
```

I don't think the notion of working on a new simulated dataset with every loop iteration really impresses me with its efficiency, but it might be if you simulating something with  a diff. I'm also not sure you have constructed `sens` and `spci` as sensitivity and specificity correctly, but at least you now can see what the results look like. There are several packages that will construct ROC curves.

This is the reason I'm doubtful that your algorithm inside the loop is correct:

```
> sens
  ss3   ss4   ss5   ss6   ss7   ss8   ss9  ss10  ss11  ss12  ss13 
0.000 0.000 0.745 0.747 0.752 0.764 0.792 0.836 0.895 0.000 0.123 
 ss14  ss15  ss16  ss17  ss18  ss19  ss20  ss21  ss22  ss23  ss24 
0.239 0.374 0.485 0.593 0.661 0.700 0.721 0.736 0.744 0.745 0.745 
 ss25  ss26  ss27  ss28  ss29  ss30  ss31  ss32  ss33  ss34  ss35 
0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.747 0.747 0.747 0.747 
 ss36  <NA>  <NA> 
0.747 0.747 0.747
```

It just doesn't look like a sensitivity result that I would expect. I might have used code like `abcd <-table( samp_h >= cut_off, samp_d >= cutoff)` to generate the values you have for a,b,c,d. You can then use matrix indexing with that table result. Another option *might* be to skip your table efforts and use this code block:

```
  a <- sum(samp_h <= cut_off)
  c <- sum(samp_h > cut_off)
  b <- sum(samp_d <= cut_off)
  d <- sum(samp_d > cut_off)
```

The `sens`-itivity results now look more sensible, but not so the `spci` results.` ( because I had the indexing wrong, now fixed in code below.)

```
cuts <- seq(from=3, to=36, by=1)
sens <- numeric(length(cuts)); spci=numeric(length(cuts))
  set.seed(666)
  samp_h <-rnorm(1000,mean=12,sd=3)
  samp_d <-rnorm(1000,mean=18,sd=6)
#Only need to make the test data.frame once
 dfrm <- data.frame( vals = c(samp_h, samp_d), 
                     grp = c( rep("H", 1000), rep("D",1000) ) )

for (i in seq_along(cuts) ) {
  cut_off<- i

  abcd <- with(dfrm, 
    table(Test_res = vals > cut_off, 
          status=grp ) )
  sens[i] <- abcd["TRUE","D"] / sum( abcd[, "D"])
  spci[i] <- abcd["FALSE", "H"] / sum( abcd[, "H"])
} 
 names(sens) <- paste0("ss",cuts)  
 names(spci) <- paste0("sp",cuts)

plot(  1-spci, sens, type="b")
text( 1-spci[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)]+.05, 
      # hack to print every 5th cutoff value
      sens[c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)], 
      label=(3:36)[ c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)] )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much. I am a two year SAS programmer actually, so using R is one thing that really makes me annoying. I always try to do something similar from SAS to R, which make me feel so bad. Thanks, really helpful. I think I will add more details below.

Comment: Hi, proffessor. I add more details about this practice. Thank you very much. I think you give the extact thing I am looking for.

Comment: There is a problem in the code. about the result of  ss3   ss4   ss5   ss6   ss7   ss8   ss9  ss10  ss11  ss12  ss13 
0.000 0.000 0.745 0.747 0.752 0.764 0.792 0.836 0.895 0.000 0.123 
 ss14  ss15  ss16  ss17  ss18  ss19  ss20  ss21  ss22  ss23  ss24 
0.239 0.374 0.485 0.593 0.661 0.700 0.721 0.736 0.744 0.745 0.745 
 ss25  ss26  ss27  ss28  ss29  ss30  ss31  ss32  ss33  ss34  ss35 
0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.745 0.747 0.747 0.747 0.747 
 ss36  <NA>  <NA> 
0.747 0.747 0.747 , because i starts from 3, so ss3 should be 0.745 instead of 0. i am thinking about how to fix this

Comment: length(sens)= 36, but sens is supposed to have 36-3+1=34 value. I think this is the problem.

Comment: I think I find the problem. In the for loop, sens[i] <- a / (a+c), but i starts 3, so the R think we assigin the 3rd value of sens to the first a / (a+c), becasue we already have sens=(0, 0, 0, ...). This is the reason why the sens looks like a mess, and also the result doesn't match my result.

Comment: Just noticed I had a `1` instead of an `i` in the index for spci. Will be replacing the whole loop anyway.

Comment: Thx for reply. I dont know why the code not work for cuts <- seq(from=3, to=36, by=0.01)

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you switched from an index that was composed of integers to an index that would be truncated. I think I have answered your question, so will not be making any more responses to edits or comments.

Comment: Thank you very much